# Как получить время в формате dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:00?

Tags: c#

Есть переменная типа DateTime. Как можно секунды изменить на 00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот ещё один простой вариант:

```
dt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Просто отнять количество секунд:

```
dt = dt.AddSeconds(-dt.Second);
```

Comment: Нижет быть, `TotalSeconds`? Чтобы убрать и миллисекунды.

Comment: @VladD, можно, жаль только, что у `DateTime` нет такого свойства ;) Вы с `TimeSpan` перепутали. И, кстати, в `TimeSpan` это свойство возвращает не просто число секунд, а тот же интервал времени, но выраженный в секундах и если его отнять, то получится 0 :)

Comment: Кстати, да, если у автора там есть и миллисекунды и тики, то ему больше подойдёт соседний ответ

Comment: А почему не просто `dt = dt.AddSeconds(-dt.Second).AddMilliseconds(-dt.Millisecond);`?

Comment: @VladD, тики останутся

Comment: Так они ж вроде просто вспомогательная штука? // Оказалось, нет. Хм.

Comment: Ну как сказать, они не отображаются при вызове ToString() и если цель - именно строковое представление, то нужно просто подобрать правильную маску, никакие манипуляции не нужны. А если взять 2 экземпляра даты одинаковые с точностью до секунды, но с разным числом тиков, то они не будут равны между собой... Так ведь?

Comment: Ага, уже сравнил между собой. https://ideone.com/tQ0bbK

Comment: @VladD, в одной миллисекунде 10 000 тиков: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timespan.tickspermillisecond(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/153014/5574962

```
public static class Test
{
    static DateTime Trim(this DateTime date, long roundTicks)
    {
        return new DateTime(date.Ticks - date.Ticks % roundTicks, date.Kind);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var dt = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
        dt = dt.Trim(TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute);
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
}
```